# OpenCart Custom Module MySQL Error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, module, opencart

So here I am codding this custom module for OpenCart and I get the following error:

```
SELECT p.upc AS product_upc, TRIM(ma.make) AS make, IFNULL(TRIM(mo.model), 0)
AS model, p2y.begin_year, p2y.end_year, IFNULL(TRIM(en.engine), 0) AS engine, 
IFNULL(TRIM(si.size), 0) AS size FROM product_to_car p2y LEFT JOIN product p ON 
p.product_id = p2y.product_id LEFT JOIN make ma ON ma.id = p2y.make_id LEFT JOIN
model mo ON mo.id = p2y.model_id LEFT JOIN `size si ON si.id = p2y.size_id`engine
en ON en.id = p2y.engine_id ORDER by ma.make, mo.model, si.size, en.engine,
p2y.begin_year in C:\wamp\www\NewDev\system\database\mysql.php on line 50
```

The **code** for that error is as following:

```
public function download($uid = 'product_id'){
    if($uid == 'product_id') {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p2y.product_id, TRIM(ma.make) AS make, IFNULL(TRIM(mo.model), 0) AS model, p2y.begin_year, p2y.end_year, IFNULL(TRIM(en.engine), 0) AS engine, IFNULL(TRIM(si.size), 0) AS size FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_car p2y LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "make ma ON ma.id = p2y.make_id LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "model mo ON mo.id = p2y.model_id LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "size` si ON si.id = p2y.size_id`" . DB_PREFIX . "engine` en ON en.id = p2y.engine_id ORDER by ma.make, mo.model, si.size, en.engine, p2y.begin_year");
    } else {
        switch($uid) {
            case 'model':
                $identifier = 'p.model AS product_model';
                break;
            case 'sku':
                $identifier = 'p.sku AS product_sku';
                break;
            case 'upc':
                $identifier = 'p.upc AS product_upc';
                break;
            case 'ean':
                $identifier = 'p.ean AS product_ean';
                break;
            case 'mpn':
                $identifier = 'p.mpn as product_mpn';
                break;
            case 'isbn':
                $identifier = 'p.isbn AS product_isbn';
                break;
            default:
                $identifier = 'p2y.product_id';
                break;
        }
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT " . $identifier . ", TRIM(ma.make) AS make, IFNULL(TRIM(mo.model), 0) AS model, p2y.begin_year, p2y.end_year, IFNULL(TRIM(en.engine), 0) AS engine, IFNULL(TRIM(si.size), 0) AS size FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_car p2y LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON p.product_id = p2y.product_id LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "make ma ON ma.id = p2y.make_id LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "model mo ON mo.id = p2y.model_id LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "size si ON si.id = p2y.size_id`" . DB_PREFIX . "engine en ON en.id = p2y.engine_id ORDER by ma.make, mo.model, si.size, en.engine, p2y.begin_year");
    }
```

I have rewritten it several times and it still does not work. If I remove this `` `" .DB_PREFIX. "size si ON si.id = p2y.size_id ``"   it works fine.

I need to get that `size` working as well.

Any clues on what might be causing this error?

Comment: The backticks after your second LEFT JOIN look suspect

Comment: I was going to update the file with the LEFT JOIN as i found that it want there. New problem came up.. as that wasn't enough, exported file is retrieving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed some backticks in your second LEFT JOIN

```
LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "size si ON si.id = p2y.size_id`" . DB_PREFIX . "engine en ON en.id = p2y.engine_id
```

Should be

```
LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "size` si ON si.id = p2y.size_id, `" . DB_PREFIX . "engine` en ON en.id = p2y.engine_id
                                ^                          ^^^                       ^
```

Comment: Also, even without the backticks it does not retrieve the error. I had them but removed it to check the difference. It was just the LEFT JOIN missing.

Comment: I had to remove the backticks after size and engine because its retrieving error.